# Two definitions for $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable $X$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{A}) \to (R,\mathcal{B})$ be measurable. Does the following two definitions for the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable $X$ coincide? If so, why?

1)$$\sigma(X)=[A\subset\Omega: X^{-1}(B)=A, \text{for some } B\in \mathcal{B}]$$

2)$$\sigma(X) = [X^{−1}(B); B ∈ \mathcal{B}]$$

Comment: Yes, those are equivalent. In the first one we are simply giving $X^{-1}(B)$ a name. In both cases, the sigma-algebra on $\Omega$ generated by $X : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ consists of preimages of Borel sets under $X$.

Comment: I got it now, thank You a lot!